# Validate an array to send to controller. Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to be able to check if the correct data is being sent, and if not to let the user know. The context of this is that I'm importing an Excel file, the data being sent to the controller is not the file itself but the data inside, in my project I have 4 different import options (users, classrooms, majors, courses) and I would like to make sure that for each import the correct data is being sent to avoid getting laravel errors, instead to be able to control those in a error message to the user. Something like `"This is the wrong Excel file, make sure you are uploading the correct file!"` if the file is wrong and doesn't have all the data it needs, or specific messages for name being missing, etc.

What is being sent is an array with the amount of rows from the excel, like 25 users, 25 objects in the array, I will show being with is in each object

```
USER

"NOMBRE" => "Abbey Knapp"
"CEDULA" => 12345
"CARNET" => 97532
"CORREO" => "ak@email.com"
"PASSWORD" => "password"
"TIPO_USUARIO" => 4
"CATEGORIA_USUARIO" => "9, 4, 1"

CLASSROOM

"NOMBRE" => "Aula1"

COURSE

"NOMBRE" => "Class 1"
"CODIGO" => 4568
 "CARRERA" => 1

MAJOR

"NOMBRE" => "Bach ING"
"CODIGO" => 1458
```

Thats what is being sent, for the major, course and classroom all that data should be required, for the user "CATEGORIA_USUARIO" is not necessary but everything else is

This is my current code, I made a `UserImportRequest`

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        '*.NOMBRE' => 'required',
        '*.CEDULA' => 'required|unique:users,card|numeric',
        '*.CARNET' => 'required|unique:users,scard|numeric',
        '*.CORREO' => 'required|email',
        '*.PASSWORD' => 'required',
        '*.TIPO_USUARIO' => 'required|exists:user_types|numeric'
    ];
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
      'NOMBRE.required' => 'El nombre es requerido!',
      'CEDULA.required' => 'La cedula es requerido!',
      'CEDULA.unique' => 'La cedula debe ser unica!',
      'CARNET.required' => 'El carnet es requerido!',
      'CARNET.unique' => 'El carnet debe ser unico!',
      'CORREO.required' => 'El correo es requerido!',
      'CORREO.email' => 'El correo debe tener el formato correcto!',
      'PASSWORD.required' => 'La contraseña es requerido!',
      'TIPO_USUARIO.required' => 'El tipo de usuario es requerido!',
      'TIPO_USUARIO.exists' => 'El tipo de usuario debe existir en la base de datos!',
    ];
}
```

In my controller import function

```
public function import(UserImportRequest $request)
{
    DB::beginTransaction();
    $validated = $request->validated();
    $users = $validated->all();

    foreach ($users as $item) {
        // save users in here
    }

    DB::commit();
    return back();
}
```

I'm getting this error

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'TIPO_USUARIO' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `user_types` where `TIPO_USUARIO` = 3)

The thing is that in the Excel file the column names are in Spanish and don't match the names on the database, so when I do `'*.TIPO_USUARIO' => 'required|exists:user_types|numeric'` it can't check for exists in the table user_types, however I still want to validate this, the name on the users table is `user_type_id`. Is there a way this is posible?

Comment: If the column option is not specified, the field name will be used. [Specifying A Custom Column Name](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-exists). So you can try something like this `'*.TIPO_USUARIO' => 'exists:user_types,id'`, where id is the column name

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ This worked, another question do you know how to send the custom validation message with data from that same item? Like if the password is missing send a message that says : the password is missing for 'user.name'. something like that?

Comment: You can do it in an after hook, in the withValidator method. Hard to explain in a comment, I would have to write an answer. But I don't quite understand how your request is. Could you do a dump and show it in the question? Or take a look at [Adding After Hooks To Form Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#creating-form-requests)

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ do a dump of what? the request when it arrives to the controller?

Comment: Yes, it can be a dump of the $users variable on your controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the original question:
If the column option is not specified, the field name will be used. Take a look at [Specifying A Custom Column Name](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-exists).

So you can do it in this way:

```
'*.TIPO_USUARIO' => 'required|exists:user_types|numeric|exists:user_types,id' //  where id is the column name
```

For the question in the comments:

> how to send the custom validation message with data from that same item? Like if the password is missing send a message that says : the password is missing for `'user.name'`. something like that?

You can do it in an after hook, in the `withValidator()` method on your `UserImportRequest` class (note that it is just an approximation, so you have the idea).

```
/**
* Configure the validator instance.
*
* @param  \Illuminate\Validation\Validator  $validator
* @return void
*/
public function withValidator($validator)
{
    $validator->after(function ($validator) {
        $users = collect($this);
        $users->each(function ($user, $key) use ($validator) {
            if ( !$user['PASSWORD'] ) {
                $validator->errors()->add('PASSWORD', 'the password is missing for '.$user['NOMBRE']);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Note you'll have to remove the custom message for `PASSWORD` in your `messages()` method

Answer (score 2):

> The thing is that in the Excel file the column names are in Spanish and don't match the names on the database, so when I do '*.TIPO_USUARIO' => 'required|exists:user_types|numeric' it can't check for exists in the table user_types, however I still want to validate this, the name on the users table is user_type_id. Is there a way this is posible?

To map your field to a different column in the database, you can do this:

```
return [
  '*.TIPO_USUARIO' => 'required|exists:user_types,user_type_id|numeric'
];
```

For the question in the comment regarding handling error messages... you can use the error directive in blade when you are redirected back to the page your form was submitted:

```
<input id="password" type="text" class="@error('password') is-invalid @enderror">

@error('password')
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
@enderror
```

More details on that here: [Displaying Validation Errors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors)